# Auto-forwarding Outlook invites as emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Long story short, my employer requires me to install some MDM software on my phone in order to access email, which I have no interest in doing.  However, I do rely heavily on my phone for meeting reminders, which I'm missing terribly.

I'm attempting to devise a workaround by which Outlook automatically forwards Meeting Invites (and Meeting updates!) to my personal mail from which I can add to my gmail calendar.  The functionality of accepting it or declining it isn't terribly important to me.

Now to my question: is there a way to detect an email as a meeting invite?  I think I've got the forwarding bit figured out.

Update: Tried with Julian's suggestion, result it failure.  Outlook obnoxiously sends a notification to the Meeting creator saying that I forward the mail on their behalf.  Doesn't look too good when it's to a personal address.

Comment: There might be corporate restrictions on forwarding your work email to a personal account.

Comment: Yes I considered that, they don't mind Meeting Invites.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a condition in the Rules settings for "which is a meeting invite or update". You can use this to create a rule on incoming email and get it forwarded to your GMail account.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that!

Comment: I must admit that I started by looking for something more complex among the form flags, only spotted it after a short while. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It appears you can choose to forward the invite as an attachment -- I'm hoping this avoids the obnoxious notification.  I just tried this in Outlook 2010, will test it out shortly.

When you create the rule, choose "forward it to people or public group as an attachment."

Potentially helpful link: http://www.send4help.net/automatically-forward-a-copy-of-meeting-invitations-outlook-2007-408

Comment: Of course, as of now it's been over 4 hours since I executed the rule and applied it to my existing inbox, which should have sent a pile of messages to my gmail -- none have arrived yet!  That's probably due to some nonsense on my work's end, however.